# Object from a Relationship is not retrieved correctly using Coredata for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Does anyone knows what an the class _NSObjectID_48_1 do??

Ok, I am doing this: I fetch the attributes (description, date and personalData)of the object Schedule in between two dates, which also has a relationship with the object Operator with only one way single (Schedule -> Operator). The fetch retrieves data, but when I want to access the properties of the Operator (like 'name') the app crashes and tells me that the "_NSObjectID_48_1" does not respond to the selector. Of course, I enabled this line during the fetch:

```
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:entityToPrefetch]];
```

This is how I set up the properties to fetch, not the whole Schedule object. Also when retrieves data, it is set to be as "NSDictionaryResultType", because otherwise it complains about not being able to get the data correctly.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Operator"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]];
            NSDictionary *relationship = [entity relationshipsByName];
            NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
            NSArray *properties = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"description"],
                                   [entityProperties objectForKey:@"date"],
                                   [relationship objectForKey:@"personalData"],nil];

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ && \
                                                                        date <= %@",
                                      [dateArray objectAtIndex:0],
                                      [dateArray lastObject]];
```

schedArray = "EXECUTE FETCH"

```
SLog(schedArray);
    SLog([schedArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    SLog([[schedArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"employee"]);
    VoicePickOperators *employee = (VoicePickOperators *)[[schedArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"employee"];
    SLog(employee);
    SLog([employee name]); <<------ Problem, I am trying to access an attribute that should be there but instead is of the type __NSObjectID_48_1
    SLog([employee description]);
```

Does anyone knows what is this happening??

Thanks!!

Comment: An `_NSObjectID_48_1` is an `NSManagedObjectID`.  Are you sure you're using the dictionary result type?

Comment: When I was asking to fetch the data, before doing it so, I set its flag: `[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];`

Comment: The solution I used was to return all objects as an `NSArrayResultType` and from there discard elements that I did not needed, but it was not the proper solution to this problem particularly. Doing it so, I could not set the `NSArray`of properties that I wanted specifically

Comment: There's no such thing as `NSArrayResultType`.

Comment: @Invoke, did you found any solution for this issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Nandha the only way I was able to jump this problem was to retrieve all objects as array as result of the fetch, instead of using dictionaries.